# Just installed php (with xampp) getting error message

Tags: php, xampp

I just installed xampp and I cannot get php to work
When I type php at the command line i get

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl'
>   (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\curl (The specified module could not be
>   found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32
>   application.)) in Unknown on line 0

The file `php_curl.dll` is at `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll`
I was thinking when it says (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)) means `php_curl.dll` is corrupt.  I tried to reinstall xampp still did not work

Comment: You could try and 'register' the curl dll. Navigate down to the ext directory (or the absolute path could be used too) then run: `regsvr32 php_curl.dll` to see if that might help.

Comment: have you enabled `curl` module in `php.ini`?